# Приложения вылетают на других машинах

Tags: c#, monogame

Перехожу с XNA на Monogame. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что надо сделать, чтоб приложения написанные на Monogame (версия 3.4, студия 2013 или 2015) могли работать на других компьютерах. Имеется два компьютера с Windows 8.1, там где я собираю - работает но на втором после появления окна приложение крэшится. Спасибо.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, текст сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: Эх, если бы там был какой-то текст, только "Прекращена работа программы "Game1", виндовс ищет что делать"

Comment: Попробуйте сделать логирование в ключевых местах приложения, чтобы локализовать ошибку.

Comment: Приложение: Game2.exe
Версия платформы: v4.0.30319
Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения.
Сведения об исключении: System.DllNotFoundException
Стек:
   в (весь текст не влез)

Comment: в Game2.Program.Main()

Comment: По всей видимости ему не хватает какой-то dll сборки, которая не найдена на другом компьютере. ТАм дальше есть "Unable to load DLL" и после него имя сборки, вот с ним и нужно разобраться.
Советую иследовать exe на втором компе c помощью http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы! Странным способом, но я узнал какой именно длл не хватало, им оказался xinput1_3.dll - с ним сразу всё заработало :-)